# Como validar fecha en c++

Tags: c++

Hola necesito validar que una cadena ingresada por el usuario sea una fecha válida y además que tenga el siguiente formato: dd/mm/yyyy. Sin embargo no lo logro. El código es el siguiente:

```
bool ValidarSiEsFecha(string cadena)
{
    bool proceso=false;

    if(cadena.size()==10)
    {
        string dia=cadena.substr(0,2);
        string mes=cadena.substr(3,2);
        string anio=cadena.substr(6);
        string separador1=cadena.substr(2,1);
        string separador2=cadena.substr(5,1);


        if(ValidarSiEsEntero(dia)&&ValidarSiEsEntero(mes)
           &&ValidarSiEsEntero(anio)&&separador1=="/"&&separador2=="/")
        {
            int annio=stoi(anio.c_str());
            int mees=stoi(mes.c_str());
            int diia=stoi(dia.c_str());

            struct tm  tmFecha;

            tmFecha.tm_year=annio;
            tmFecha.tm_mday=diia;
            tmFecha.tm_mon=mees;
            tmFecha.tm_hour=0;
            tmFecha.tm_min=0;
            tmFecha.tm_sec=0;
                tmFecha.tm_isdst=-1;

            if(mktime(&tmFecha)!=-1){

                proceso=true;
                cout <<"entro";
            }else{
                cout <<"no entri"<<mktime(&tmFecha)<<endl;
                proceso=false;
            }

        }else{
            proceso=false;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        proceso= false;
    }
    return proceso;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No reinventes la rueda, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ya dispone de herramientas para leer fechas, usa [`std::get_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time):

```
std::string fecha;
std::tm tm;

if (std::cin >> std::get_time(&tm, "%d/%m/%Y"))
    std::cout << "Fecha correcta";
else
    std::cout << "Fecha incorrecta";
```

Pedes encapsularlo en una función:

```
bool ValidarSiEsFecha(const std::string &posible_fecha)
{
    std::stringstream fecha;
    std::tm tm;

    fecha << posible_fecha;

    return static_cast<bool>(fecha >> std::get_time(&tm, "%d/%m/%Y"));
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDbSsNAEH3ufMUQSUlASVr0pQl50x8QBJ/CdrONA3sJu5Mn8dtjLrWNSh/nXGbOGdl1D1IL2w7DHVmp@0ZhSS6wV8JUcMW0k0KrNULOCEvdGgo/Pjg6p/FNaGqEf6Xn8KLkh0iks4ExcHM4jEqyLW47F@ioVX2aBCl8wmZFL@tw5oozwwbZFACbGcWyxF8rJsYr7r0d7wgmWUsRuJzyVMliqaolQqu4ZjIq2bK5xyhusthk8XuUpgV8AZBlNIJs8jfVjTzzJMlO@y9R6ITJvzcsXVPYnD2u56lHNLMonfdKsojGC0oHdUM2Pv0qvHTOx@jDsHvK8sdsn@938A0)</kbd>.